# pointer to a function and callbacks

Tags: c

I'm supposed to make function "print", print a value of "greatest" or "lowest function" depending on the user's choice

```
void print(int*walk,int*stop,int (*ptr)(int,int))
{
    for(walk; walk < stop; walk++)
    {
        printf("%d ",*walk);
    }

}
```

so this function here has to be somehow edited and I'm kind of lost.
Pasting the rest of my code down below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
void print(int*walk,int*stop,int (*ptr)(int,int));
void randm(int*walk,int*stop,int p,int q);
int greatest(int*walk,int*stop);
int lowest(int*walk,int*stop);
int main()
{

    int N;
    printf("Pass number of arguments:");
    scanf("%d",&N);

    int *A =(int*)malloc(N*sizeof(int));


    randm(A,A+N,10,15);
    print(A,A+N,greatest(A,A+N));


    free(A);
    return 0;
}
void print(int*walk,int*stop,int (*ptr)(int,int))
{
    for(walk; walk < stop; walk++)
    {
        printf("%d ",*walk);
    }

}
void randm(int*walk,int*stop,int p,int q)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(walk; walk < stop; walk++)
    {
        *walk = rand()%q + p;
    }

}

int greatest(int*walk,int*stop)
{
    int value = *walk;
    for(walk+1; walk < stop; walk++)
    {
        if(*walk > value)
            value = *walk;
    }

    return value;
}
int lowest(int*walk,int*stop)
{
    int value = *walk;
    for(walk+1; walk < stop; walk++)
    {
        if(*walk < value)
            value = *walk;
    }
    return value;
}
```

edit.
Instead of 2 functions "greatest", "lowest" I'm supposed to make one function that takes 3 arguments - pointer to the first element of the array, pointer to the end of the array, and 3rd argument which is int (*ptr)(int, int) - "greatest" or "lowest"
Then I'm supposed to print it depending on the user's choice which would be
print(A,A+N,greatest(A,A+N));
or
print(A,A+N,lowest(A,A+N));

Comment: Clearly you did not understand the purpose of the exercise about function pointers

Comment: You need to describe the problem better.  What choice will be presented to the user?  What calculations must be done?  What exactly will `print` need to print on the screen?  Why is `print` receiving a function pointer as its third argument?  Can you provide some example inputs to the program along with corresponding desired outputs?

Comment: `void print (int*walk,int*stop,int (*ptr)(int,int)) { printf("%d ", ptr (walk, stop)); }` ??; You are just outputting the result of the function passed as the argument to `print()` passing the `walk` and `stop` parameters to the function. So if you pass `lowest`, it will print the lowest values, or `greatest`, it will print the greatest value.

Comment: Presumably the idea is that `print()` will receive as an argument a pointer to the function to call.  Its third argument seems suited to that.  The type of that argument is not compatible with functions `greatest()` and `lowest()`, however, because the argument types do not match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `print()` to output the `lowest` or `greatest` by passing a function pointer, you simply call the function using the pointer within `print()`. In your example `ptr` is a pointer to a function returning `int` and taking two *pointers-to* `int` as its parameters. That matches the function declarations for `lowest` and `greatest`, e.g.

```c
int greatest (int *walk, int *stop);
int lowest (int *walk, int *stop);
```

In order to use either in `print()` depending on which is called, you use `ptr` as the function name and use it like you would any other function. Here,

```c
void print (int *walk, int *stop, int (*ptr)(int*,int*))
{
    printf ("%d\n", ptr(walk, stop));
}
```

(**note:** a `'\n'` has been used instead of following output with a space in the `printf()` format string - adjust as desired)

To then call `print()` to output the `lowest` and `greatest` values in your block of memory `A`, you would do:

```c
    print (A, A+N, lowest);       /* output lowest */

    print (A, A+N, greatest);     /* output greatest */
```

**Other Problems to Address**

You have a number of other problems you should address. To use the `time()` function in `srand()` you should `#include <time.h>`. Secondly, `srand (time(NULL));` is only called once in `main()`. There is no way to limit the number of calls to `randm()` to one. (i.e. it *can* be called more than once, not that it *is*).

You must validate EVERY user-input. If the user slips and enters `'r'` instead of `5`, your program fails to handle the invalid input and invokes *Undefined Behavior* in that case. Always validate user-input, e.g.

```c
    if (scanf ("%d", &N) != 1) {  /* validate EVERY user-input */
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
```

Always validate EVERY memory allocation. When (not if) `malloc()` fails, it returns `NULL`. If you fail to catch the error and then derefererence the `NULL` pointer, *Undefined Behavior* (and likely a SegFault) results. You validate the allocation the same way you validate input, by ***checking the return value***, e.g.

```c
    int *A = malloc (N * sizeof *A);
    if (!A) {                     /* validate EVERY allocation */ 
        perror ("malloc-A");
        return 1;
    }
```

(**note:** In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714))

Finally, while not an error (the preprocessor ignores whitespace), please space your code consistently to make your code much more readable (especially for older eyes). However you like is fine, as long as it is consistent and readable. Spacing your code a bit and putting everything above into a short example, you could do:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>

void print (int *walk, int *stop, int (*ptr)(int*,int*));
void randm (int *walk, int *stop, int p, int q);
int greatest (int *walk, int *stop);
int lowest (int *walk, int *stop);

int main (void) {

    int N = 0;
    
    fputs ("Pass number of arguments: ", stdout);
    if (scanf ("%d", &N) != 1) {  /* validate EVERY user-input */
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    int *A = malloc (N * sizeof *A);
    if (!A) {                     /* validate EVERY allocation */ 
        perror ("malloc-A");
        return 1;
    }
    
    srand (time(NULL));           /* only called once in main() */
    
    randm (A, A+N, 10, 15);
    
    fputs ("min : ", stdout);     /* prefix for minimum */
    print (A, A+N, lowest);       /* output lowest */
    
    fputs ("min : ", stdout);     /* prefix for maximum */
    print (A, A+N, greatest);     /* output greatest */

    free (A);
}

void print (int *walk, int *stop, int (*ptr)(int*,int*))
{
    printf ("%d\n", ptr(walk, stop));
}

void randm (int *walk, int *stop, int p, int q)
{
    for (; walk < stop; walk++) {
        *walk = rand()%q + p;
    }

}

int greatest (int *walk, int *stop)
{
    int value = *walk++;
    
    for (; walk < stop; walk++) {
        if (*walk > value)
            value = *walk;
    }

    return value;
}

int lowest (int *walk, int *stop)
{
    int value = *walk++;
    
    for (; walk < stop; walk++) {
        if (*walk < value)
            value = *walk;
    }
    
    return value;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/walkstop
Pass number of arguments: 200
min : 10
min : 24
```